# How to convert functions into usable buttons?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get buttons to calculate Celsius values and convert them to Fahrenheit through a function. Everything I have tried has not worked as I would like it to. The value of the buttons should be the value in Celsius to be converted into Fahrenheit.

I have tried defining the arguments in the function (button1, 2, and 3), changing the onclick in HTML, changing variable names, and double checking everything.

HTML

```
<input type="button" name="button1" value="10" onclick="conversion1;" />
<input type="button" name="button2" value="20" onclick="conversion2" />
<input type="button" name="button3" value="30" onclick="conversion3" />
```

JavaScript

```
function conversion (button1, button2, button3) {
  var conversion1 = ((button1 * 9) / 5) + 32;
  var conversion2 = ((button2 * 9) / 5) + 32;
  var conversion3 = ((button3 * 9) / 5) + 32;
}

var conversionInput = conversion(10, 20, 30);
```

I expect the output to be three separate buttons that, when clicked, show their respective Fahrenheit conversions based on their values.

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what you mean, and the code snippet you've provided doesn't make any sense. Perhaps take a look at MDN: [Introduction to events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)

Comment: I'm not sure that we can really help here other than write the code for you. The main problem appears to be that you appear to lack any programming experience. Maybe you should learn how to program javascript first.

Comment: Sorry, but you need learn more JavaScript before you start creating your own solution. You can't just skip learning and throw random code in hope that it will work. Read good book first. Or follow some online video tutorial. Try [udemy](https://www.udemy.com/). They have cheap courses that give comprehensive knowledge.

Comment: I'm reading Sams Teach Yourself JavaScript (7th Edition) and this is one of the exercises in the book. There is no answer key and I couldn't find anything on Google. That's why I asked the question here. I've reread the chapter relating to the problem I am trying to solve multiple times but I still don't understand it. I feel like I should know how to do it considering it's an exercise at the end of the chapter.

Comment: @DaGallane don't give up. Sometimes we really need the first solutions in order just to understand how that subject of study works. I gave one solution below to you. Feel free to ask more if you need.

Answer (score 0):

One function is enough to calculate all of them based on the value on the button itself:

After clicking a button, the result will be displayed in an span (you could return the value as well, if you need it somewhere else):

```js
function conversion(temp) {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = ((temp * 9) / 5) + 32;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" name="button1" value="10" onclick="conversion(this.value);" />
<input type="button" name="button2" value="20" onclick="conversion(this.value);" />
<input type="button" name="button3" value="30" onclick="conversion(this.value);" />

Result: <span id="result"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use button @ManuelMannhardt if the way to go, but for that use a text input is much better:

You can use the onclick event directly in the component, as you're doing:

```js
function calculate() {
    var inputWithValue = document.querySelector('#val');
    var spanForResult = document.querySelector('#resultValue');
    spanForResult.innerHTML = ((inputWithValue.value * 9) / 5) + 32;
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="val" />
<input type="button" id="convert" onclick="calculate()" value="Convert to Fahrenheit" />
<div id="result">Result: <span id="resultValue"></span> </div>
```

But it's better not to mix code with html. Here is what I mean:

```js
var button = document.querySelector('#convert');
var inputWithValue = document.querySelector('#val');
var spanForResult = document.querySelector('#resultValue');

button.onclick = ()=>{
    spanForResult.innerHTML = ((inputWithValue.value * 9) / 5) + 32;
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="val" />
<input type="button" id="convert" value="Convert to Fahrenheit" />
<div id="result">Result: <span id="resultValue"></span> </div>
```

Explaining also the `()=>{` is the same as `function() {`

Also please don't forget that SO's Javascript tag has lots of references to help you learn: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you need but in case you want to change the value/text of the buttons when clicked you can use something like this:

```html
<script>
function convert(el){
  //get the value from unit custom attribute, c (Celsius) or f (Fahrenheit)
  var unit = el.getAttribute("unit")
 // if is Celsius convert to Fahrenheit else do reverse
  if (unit == "c"){
    el.setAttribute("unit","f") //set unit to f
    el.value = ((el.value * 9) / 5) + 32 //set value with new value calculated C --> F
  }
  else{
    el.setAttribute("unit","c") //set unit to c
    el.value = ((el.value - 32) * 5) / 9 //set value with new value calculated F --> C
  }
}
</script>

<input type="button" name="button1" value="10" unit="c" onclick="convert(this);">
<input type="button" name="button2" value="20" unit="c" onclick="convert(this);">
<input type="button" name="button3" value="30" unit="c" onclick="convert(this);">
```

Hope this help you.